Pyspark 3.5.0 fixing vulnerabilities in JAR files
I'm working on a Python project that depends on PySpark 3.5.1.
During the CI/CD pipeline, a Nexus scan identified vulnerabilities in PySpark's dependencies:

avro-ipc-1.11.2.jar
jackson-mapper-asi-1.9.13.jar

These JAR files are sub-dependencies of PySpark.
We use a plain requirements.txt file, and there's no straightforward way to exclude or override these sub-dependencies. I attempted to use Poetry and constraints.txt, but since these are JAR files, it didn't work as expected.
Could someone provide guidance on how to address these vulnerabilities?

Those JARs are presumably included with that version of PySpark and PySpark depends on (exactly) them. I think you'd need to evaluate whether the vulnerabilities found by this scan are actual vulnerabilities you need to address.
